# Decoding a hex string into 4 pieces that maps to a binary map of values

Tags: php, hex, hexdump, raw-data

I am trying to decode a supposedly hex string. In **MS SQL Server (11.0.2100)** the data has the type of `char(8)`.

In the manuals there was no clear way of decoding the data but it documents what it contains:

> Given a hex string ie. `0001003F` with a length of 4. The lower byte
>   is on the right, the higher byte is on the left. For each of the 4
>   '`bytes`' a reference table that maps a 'bit' to a certain truthy
>   value was given. A bit order is also given having the bit 0 or the bit
>   in right most being the 1st bit, ..., etc.

The table looks like this:

1st 'byte':

```
|Bit Order  | Description   |   1               |   0               |   trigger     |
|-----------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------------|
|BIT0       | state foo     | state foo is ON   | State foo is OFF  |   high level  |
|BIT1       | state bar     | in state bar      | not in state bar  |   high level  |
|                                   ... 
|BIT7       | state bazz    | in state bazz     | not in state bazz |   high level  |
```

(3 more tables follows for the next 3 other 'byte's ..., each of the 4 'byte's supposedly has 8 equal number of 'bits')

I thought the way of decoding this data is to split the hex string into 4 parts and convert them into a binary string width a fixed with of 8.

In `PHP`, taken the example hex '`0001003F`', the first byte was '`3F`', having the converted to binary, `0011 1111` (space for clarity). Then, inferred that the value for the first byte was:

`'state foo is on', 'in state bar', ..., 'not in state bazz'`.

I also tried to do: `hex2bin("0001003F")` but it outputs `strin(4) " #  "`.

Is this the correct way of decoding this data?

*(I beg your pardon if the tags are incorrect.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 4 bytes fit into the storage for [integer type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) on almost all platforms (32-bit and higher), you can convert the hex string to integer, then use the [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) to check if specific bit is set:

```
$hex_str = '0001003F';
$flags = base_convert($hex_str, 16, 10);

foreach (range(0, 31) as $bit) {
  printf("Bit %d: %d\n", $bit, (bool) ($flags & (1 << $bit)));
}
```

*Output*

```
Bit 0: 1
Bit 1: 1
Bit 2: 1
Bit 3: 1
Bit 4: 1
Bit 5: 1
Bit 6: 0
...
Bit 15: 0
Bit 16: 1
Bit 17: 0
...
Bit 31: 0
```

If bit `$bit` is set (1), then the state corresponding to this bit is *on*.

The code converts the hex string `$hex_str` to an integer `$flags` with the help of [`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function. The loop iterates bit numbers in range `[0;31]` (starting from the least significant bit). The `(1 << $bit)` expression is the value `1` shifted to the left by `$bit` bits. Thus, if bit number `$bit` is set, then the result of the bitwise *AND* operation is a non-zero integer. The result is cast to [*boolean*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) type to produce `1`, if the result is non-zero, and `0` otherwise.

It is easy to see that you can test a number of bits with a single bitwise *AND* operation, e.g.:

```
// Check if at least one of three bits is set, 3rd, 10th, or 11th
$mask = (1 << 3) | (1 << 10) | (1 << 11);
if ($flags & $mask)
  printf("At least one of the bits from mask 0x%x is set\n", $mask);
```

*Output*

```
At least one of the bits from mask 0xc08 is set
```

Comment: My solution was quite similar to your answer. Is this kind of encoding/decoding exists in practice? I am really not familiar to this encoding/decoding scheme.

Comment: @javiniar.leonard, it depends on the problem. Particularly, I don't think that `CHAR(8)` is a good choice for a bit mask. If it is known for sure that the number of bits will not be greater than 64, then I'd rather use `BIGINT`. If the properties of the states are likely to grow, or the states may have relationships with other tables in future, I would create a table for the states and a table for object states like `obj_states (object_id, state_id)`. However, some DBMS implementations may feature bitwise operations on `BINARY` fields (a planned extension for MySQL 8.0).

Comment: But you obviously save some space by storing the hex characters at the price of code complexity. You might compress them better with a `BINARY` field; `HEX(bin_field)` could return the hex string for further processing in PHP.

Comment: Finally, I was able to compare the data that I was trying to decode to another app that consumes the same data and it seems to be ok.